# How to delay GWT datagrid row selection until load is complete?

Tags: gwt, datagrid, selection

Is there any way that I can execute a method to select a row in GWT DataGrid after the grid is loaded completely?

I am trying to select a specific row in the table, in cases where the table load is taking more time, the selection does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you fire the selection event in the callback of the loading event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Scheduler.scheduleDeferred(new Command() {...});](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html) to delay the logic until all scripts are executed.

If your data is loaded from the server, put the Scheduler in the onSuccess() method. You can check the time it took for the server to answer to cancel your selection.